# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for referincing projects

Tags: java

i have 2 project in eclipse. one having the mailn method referring the other without a main method.  after adding the reference i am getting the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:Exception in thread "main"

Comment: which is the class that is not found? also have you added classpath entry to the second project

Comment: Please provide more information...

Comment: I suspect you aren't properly including your second project.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a jar from `the project without main`, and adding the jar to the classpath of `the project with main method`.

**To create jar:**

Select the project without main method, and perform the following steps:

```
File -> Export -> Java -> Jar File
```

**To add the jar as library to the project with main method**

Select the project with main method, and perform the following steps:

```
Build Path -> Configure Build Path... -> Select Libraries tab -> Add External JARS
```

Alternatively, you may create a folder called `lib`, and put the jar in the `lib` directory, then you may perform the following steps:

```
Build Path -> Configure Build Path... -> Select Libraries tab -> Add JARS
```

Comment: This would give the error that there's no main method, not noclassdeffounderror.

Comment: If user2491918 did not properly add `the library project` to the classpath of `the main project`, it would give him `NoClassDefFoundError` when he tries to access the resources from `the library project`

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError occurs when the source was successfully compiled, but at runtime, the required class files were not found. This may be something that can happen in the distribution or production of JAR files, where not all the required class files were included. So build library project jar file with all its dependency or classpath jar files included and add that library jar file into your main project classpath